# Get color from floating action button and use it to change background color on edittext

Tags: java, android, button, colors, background-color

I was wondering if there was a way to change the background color of an edittext object by clicking on a floating action button. Now I don't need the code for setting up colors or any of the sort, just the part that involves storing the color from the floating action button and assigning it to the background color of an edittext object.

I tried the solution from this link:
[How to get background color of button. On click action depends on background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314555/how-to-get-background-color-of-button-on-click-action-depends-on-background-col)

The link above only works for a regular button, but for floating action button I get an error that reads:

```
android.support.design.widget.ShadowDrawableWrapper cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
```

Is there a way for me to cast Color Drawable to a FAB to do what I'm trying to do above?

Here's what I tried:

```
FloatingActionButton btnTag = new FloatingActionButton(R.id.some_button);
ColorDrawable someColor = (ColorDrawable) btnTag.getBackground();
int colorId = someColor.getColor(); 

//Then set edittext's background color to same color as FAB with id some_button
EditText et= new EditText(R.id.some_et);
et.setBackgroundColor(colorId);
```

But this doesn't seem to work possibly due to how the FAB is drawn, unlike a regular button which is a square and has no rounded corners. So I was wondering if there's any way to edit the code I provided to make it work as expected?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
I fore-got to mention that I need it to work on api 11 and above.

Comment: `getContentBackground` should return a drawable without the shadow. At least that's what the documentation says

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a method called getContentBackground for a floating action button. How would I call it?

Comment: Are you not using this  Floating action button class?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Comment: I am, but it seems to give me the "cannot resolve method getContentBackground()" message. Do you know if the method works on api level 11?

Comment: Hmm, most of the methods on the documentation say which API they were added, but I cannot find any reference on that class. I would assume the Support Design library should work on lower API versions

Comment: It seems to be for higher api levels according to this link, I don't think it will work then: https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23.2.0/changes/android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.html

Answer (score 0):

```
FloatingActionButton btnTag = new FloatingActionButton(R.id.some_button);
Drawable background = btnTag.getContentBackground();

EditText et= new EditText(R.id.some_et);
et.setBackground(background);
```

Comment: This would work, but I foregot to mention that I need it to work on api level 11 and above, and this only works on api 16+. I'll update the question, but thanks for providing the example